# WP создание страницы Регистрации нового пользователя без плагинов

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вот [тут](https://wpmag.ru/2015/wordpress-multisite-signup/) пишут что страница регистрации нового пользователя, это по сути `/wp-admin` с GET параметром, а если точнее, то `wp-login.php?action=register` У меня стоит пустая WP, но почему-то не дает попасть на настройки, что б можно было зарегистрироваться. Как это исправить...? Как давать регистрировать пользователям на сайте без установки доп. плагинов.

Comment: У Вас в настройках стоит галочка на Настройки -> Общие -> "Любой может зарегестрироваться"?

Comment: Ага, спасибо, а дальше я так понимаю необходимо производить какие-то настройки с SMTP почтой, что бы эти письма регистрации приходили пользователю? * поскольку там только два поля - Email | Login.

Comment: Не совсем понял, при чем количество полей к email-ам и SMTP)

Comment: На локальном сервере создать таким образом нового пользователя, что бы протестировать этот способ мне не удалось. Полей с паролями как обычно принято в WP в дефолтных настройках нету...

Comment: У Вас скорее всего отправка email c локального сервера не настроена.